# Why flutter_svg package not working in a package?

Tags: flutter, svg, flutter-dependencies

My problem is, I am writing a package and it is contains some helpful widgets. And what I do succeed is simply, create a widget with uses my package assets and show it to any app.

So;

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_svg: ^1.0.3

flutter:
assets:

- assets/illustrations/

I add correctly the svg assets to my package, and I call it on my widget like;

```
SvgPicture.asset(
        "assets/illustrations/xx.svg",
        width: 50,
        height: 220.0,
      )
```

if we assume my widget name XX

I am using the XX widget in my app like XX();

and I am getting these errors;

```
The following assertion was thrown resolving a single-frame picture stream:
```

Unable to load asset: assets/illustrations/....svg

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)

#1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:72:27)

#2      AssetBundlePictureProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter_svg/src/picture_provider.dart:546:25)

But if I do same steps for adding assets and using same way the same .svg file on my real app, it is working correctly.

So here is my question; What is the difference using a svg asset in a package and call it from the real app project.

and lastly, I am sorry for my poor english but any idea will be gladly accepted, thank u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71750574/15111208) and what we need is simply, give the package: "", parameter.

```
 SvgPicture.asset(
        "assets/illustrations/xxx.svg",
        width: 50,
        height: 220.0,
        package: "packageName",
      ),
```